# JAVAFX CHARTS: Setting origin point on category axis

Tags: javafx-8, bar-chart, linechart

I am in need to add a zero point for category axis in javafx line chart. In the image I want some "T0" to represent the zero mark of origin on the x axis, so that I can mark point on y axis as  on the chart.
[sample line chart ( looks like bar chart !)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWj0g.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear what you're asking, but if you want the pixel coordinates of the left end of the x-axis, you can do

```
Category xAxis = ... ;

// ...

double leftEnd = xAxis.getDisplayPosition(value0) - xAxis.getCategorySpacing();
```

where `value0` is the x-value of the first data point.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but what I really want is to permanently shift "T0" in question img to origin point, in which case origin can be marked as <T0,0>. I have tried using `xAxis.setStartMargin( )`, but the result varies on number of points on the x-axis.